# How delete non-contiguous rows using xlwings 0.18.0?

Tags: xlwings

How can I delete non-contiguous rows using xlwings 0.18.0?
Using VBA a can do this Range("1:7, 9:9").EntireRow.Delete

xlwings as xw

'''
Sub Delete_NonContigous_Rows_Using_VBA()
    'Delete rows 1,2,3 ... 7 and 9
    Range("1:7, 9:9").EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
'''

## How can I do this in xlwings==0.18.0 ?

xw.Range("1:7","9:9").api.Delete()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this

```html
xw.Range(xw.Range('1:7'), xw.Range('9:9')).delete()
```

But I'm stuck how to count columns

```html
xw.api.UsedRange.Columns.count
```